# Keil uVision 5: How can I copy array data out into a file on my PC?

Tags: debugging, copy-paste, keil

I've just now started to learn programming a Cortex-m0 based microcontroller which is on a EVK connected to my computer by USB. The expected IDE/toolchain to be used for this EVK is uVision 4/5 and I'm using uVision5. The debugger is configured to J-LINK/J-TRACE.

I have a 1000 bytes array and I need to copy the data out of the uVision IDE for further analysis, how can I do it? I'm really stuck here. I'm used to TI's CCS studio, in which it was just a matter of selecting and copying the variable from the Watch window.

Although, in uVision, I'm able to see the entire byte array as rows by expanding it in the Watch window, I'm unable to select them to copy them.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Command Window. You can enable it by: Menue->View->Command Window.

In the Command Window set cursor after the '>', then type:

```
D <start address>, <end address>
```

and hit enter. This output you can copy to your clipboard. I used the column mode of Notepad++ to sanitize the output.

Example:

```
D 0x1000, 0x0fabb10
```